# How to get day of year as an integer with simpledateformat?

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date

I have a simple program that asks a user to enter a date in a MM-dd-yyyy format. How can I get the day of the year from this input? For example if the user enters "06-10-2008" the day of the year would be the 162nd day considering this was a leap year.

Here's my code so far:

```
System.out.println("Please enter a date to view (MM/DD/2008):");

        String date = sc.next();

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        Date date2=null;
        try {
            //Parsing the String
            date2 = dateFormat.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {                
            System.out.println("Invalid format, please enter the date in a MM-dd-yyyy format!");
            continue;
        } //End of catch
        System.out.println(date2);
    }
```

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only notoriously troublesome, along with `Date` it is also long outdated. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date2); //Assuming this is date2 variable from your code snippet
int dayOfYear = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using Java 8+, you could use the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class to parse it with a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) like

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy");
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("06-10-2008", fmt).getDayOfYear());
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
162
```

Comment: This will work nicely in Java 6 and 7 too if you add [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to your project. On (older) Android use the Android edition of same: [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date2);
System.out.println("Day of year = " + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).